# FFMPEG MultiPlex all video's to all audio's

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, bash-scripting, multiplexing

(windows 10 64)
I have seen & read MULTIPLE (50+) answers to forms of this question but not for what Im trying to do.

I have a folder with 30+ short clips (few seconds each) mp4's
I also have a folder with 8 or say audio tracks mp3's
The audio track needs to end when the video ends (so dont have black video for 4 minutes if the audio file is longer then the video)

Im trying to multiplex all the files together (I know alot of files D: but thats why i dont want to do this by hand)
Currently im doing them one at a time like this:

```
ffmpeg -i videoFile.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i audioFile.mp3 -filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest" -c:v copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

i have seen a bash that does this but only if the audio and video have the same name, so its not really a multi plex :(

The goal is to lose no video quality, and combine each video in one folder, with EACH file also in a separate folder, and output them (i guess combine the Video and audio names?) to a separate folder

the old bat file i saw but doesnt itterate all the audio with ALL the video is:

```
@echo off
:: set paths (no quotes)
set ffmpeg=C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe
set outfolder=E:\Template\Video Outro\FFBatch

@echo.
@echo on
for %%f in (*.mp4) do "%ffmpeg%" -y ^
  -hide_banner ^
  -i "%%~dpnxf"  -i "%%~dpnf.mp3" ^
  -filter_complex "amix=inputs=2:duration=shortest" ^
  -c:v copy -movflags ^
  -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -shortest ^
  "%outfolder%\%%~nf-remux.mp4"
@echo off
if errorlevel 1 pause
@echo.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so finally remembered what the programming argument/logic was called that i was trying to do here
NESTED
so i googled nested batch arguments and tested it (it is working)

I did have to change complex sections for myself as i did not have any audio tracks on the video's (intentionally) but this is working beautifully for me now :)

```
@echo off
:: set paths (no quotes)
set ffmpeg=C:\Windows\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe
set outfolder=E:\Template\Video Outro\FFBatch

@echo.
@echo on
for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
  for %%a in (*.mp3) do  "%ffmpeg%" -y ^
  -i "%%~dpnxf" -stream_loop -1 -i "%%~dpna.mp3" ^
  -c:v copy -shortest -map 0:v -map 1:a^
  "%outfolder%\%%~nf-%%~na-remux.mp4")
@echo off
if errorlevel 1 pause
@echo.
```